# How to use react-semantic-ui transition.group on map

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a bunch of cards and I would like to have transition with a delay on each item but couldn't really figure it out on how to implement this.

According to the documentation I have to use something like this:

```
 <Transition.Group
          as={List}
          duration={200}
          divided
          size='huge'
          verticalAlign='middle'
        >
          {items.map((item) => (
            <List.Item key={item}>
              <Image avatar src={`/images/avatar/small/${item}.jpg`} />
              <List.Content header={_.startCase(item)} />
            </List.Item>
          ))}
        </Transition.Group>
```

but I didn't really get what is `as={List}` doing there. That's why couldn't really go forward with my solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is what I have:

```
 <Card.Group itemsPerRow={itemsPerRow} centered>
          {data.map((e) => {
            const dateToFormat = e.created_at;
            const userIndex = data.indexOf(e);

            return (

              <Card raised>
                <Image
                  src={readmeFiles[userIndex].image}
                  wrapped
                  size="large"
                  ui={false}
                  onClick={() => {
                    const index = data.indexOf(e);
                    clickHandler(index);
                  }}
                />
                <Card.Content>
                  <Card.Header></Card.Header>
                  <Card.Meta>
                    <span className="date">{e.name}</span>
                  </Card.Meta>
                  <Card.Description>{e.description}</Card.Description>
                </Card.Content>
                <Card.Content extra>
                  <a>
                    <Icon name="calendar alternate outline" />
                    Created: <Moment date={dateToFormat} fromNow />
                  </a>
                </Card.Content>
              </Card>

            );
          })}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `as={List}` tells semantic to render this `Transition.Group` component as a `List` component, which serves as a parent to the `List.Item` components. Those will only render correctly if they have a `List` as parent. You can check the resulting html out [here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/transition/#types-group).

The following snippet:

```js
<Transition.Group
  as={List}
  duration={200}
  divided
  size='huge'
  verticalAlign='middle'
>
  {items.map((item) => (
    <List.Item key={item}>
      <Image avatar src={`/images/avatar/small/${item}.jpg`} />
      <List.Content header={_.startCase(item)} />
    </List.Item>
  ))}
</Transition.Group>
```

Generates the following html:

```html
<div role="list" class="ui huge divided middle aligned list">
    <div role="listitem" class="item fade visible transition">
      <img src="/images/avatar/small/ade.jpg" class="ui avatar image" />
      <div class="content"><div class="header">Ade</div></div>
    </div>
    <div role="listitem" class="item fade visible transition">
      <img src="/images/avatar/small/chris.jpg" class="ui avatar image" />
      <div class="content"><div class="header">Chris</div></div>
    </div>
    <div role="listitem" class="item fade visible transition">
      <img src="/images/avatar/small/christian.jpg" class="ui avatar image" />
      <div class="content"><div class="header">Christian</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the first div says `role="List"` and has the `list` css class added. In your case the parent would be the `Card.Group` component.